# How to iterate through a template function with int parameter?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

So I had sort of a template function
`template<int i> task();`
You may also think of it as a type with coresponding constructor if needed.
`template<int i> struct task{ task();};`
And I would like to iterate `i` through an interval.
Which means,
`task<0>(); task<1>(); ... task<ConstantVal>();`
Furthermore, I would like to use similar style as if writing any usual for loop, that is to say, I would like to avoid creating a template class each time encountering such similar situation. Instead, I would like to just use an template, say, `template<int s, int j, class callable> struct ForLoop;` and simply apply something like `ForLoop<s,t,taskTemplate>()`
But it requries me to pass the template as an argument, which is a not syntatically legal. Is there some work around for these kind of iterate problem?

Below is some work around. But I don't think that is a great solution for reasons I've mentioned above.

```
template<int s, int t>
struct ForLoop{
    ForLoop(){
        task<s>(); ForLoop<s+1,t>::ForLoop();
    }
};
template<int s>
struct ForLoop<s,s>{
    ForLoop(){}
};
```

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Showing some psuedo-code or example code would clarify your question a lot.

Comment: If you want to loop over `task<i>`, why are you creating it as a template?    That creates a family of `task`s, not a single type for which the value of `i` can be set at runtime - and that prevents what you seek.

Comment: @ryhp I am using c++11.
@Peter Because I need to access some other template object that accepts only constant values.
@super Here is my code, but I don't think that is a good way to implement it.
```
template<int s, int t>
struct ForLoop{
    ForLoop(){
        task<s>(); ForLoop<s+1,t>::ForLoop();
    }
};
template<int s>
struct ForLoop<s,s>{
    ForLoop(){}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use something like (C++14):

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename F>
void ForEachIndex(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f)
{
    int dummy[] = {0, /* Handles empty Is. following cast handle evil operator comma */
                   (static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>())), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable
}

template <std::size_t N, typename F>
void ForEachIndex(F&& f)
{
    ForEachIndex(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Usage:

```
const auto start = 42;
ForEachIndex<4>([&](auto i){ task<start + i()>(); }); // task<42>(), .., task<45>()
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/528c901cb52cf089)

For C++11:

- implementation of `make_index_sequence`/`index_sequence` can be found.
- generic lambda should be replaced by old functor:

  ```
  struct MyFunctor {
      template <std::size_t I>
      void operator()(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) const {
          // ...
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: Which part is unclear for you ? You might also look "iterate over tuple" for some details.

Comment: I'm actually not that familiar with C++14
but how come the lambda parameter being able to be passed as a template parameter? I mean, it is a variable, isn't it?

Comment: Generic lambda would receive different type as `auto`: `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>`, ..,  `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N - 1>`. Those type can provides the `I` at compile time. so, we call `f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>())`, .., `f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N - 1>())`.

Comment: alright!
but what does integral_constant and index_sequence do?
I still cannot get it

Comment: `index_sequence` is mostly a (compile) collection of `std::size_t`, `integral_constant` is a type to wrap constant value into a type.